# RS422 communication using PySerial (Raspberry PI)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, usb, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with a measuring device using python with PySerial.
I have it hooked up to a USB to RS422 convertor by Waveshare.
When I send data in the led lights up, but I get no response from the device.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
print(ser.name)
print(ser.baudrate)

message = 'GETINFO'
message = message.encode('ascii')
ser.write(message)
#time.sleep(1)

read = ser.read(100)
print(read)
ser.close()
```

I think it must be something I am not understanding about RS422 communication.

I tried sending different messages and setting up the serial port in different ways but none have worked so far.

Comment: Do you know that your device works? Have you considered a loopback arrangement to test all your software and hardware up to, but excluding your device?

Comment: Please include the exact vendor and model of the measurement device you are using, as well as the usage manual and communication/command/response specification documents. Is your program written according to its specification document? Or have you tried using some general-purpose communication terminal software instead of your program to see what kind of results you get?
Please refer to these help articles to improve your question articles. [How do I ask...?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create...Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)